# UISearchBar Scope Button Color / Formatting

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Simple and short:
How do I change the color / textcolor / font etc. of a "Scope Button"? 
Is there a way at all or do i have to re-implement the whole thing all by myself?

thanks in advance

sam

Comment: Having searched for this and having looked at Class Dumps earlier, it doesn't seem like it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't using SDK 3.1.3.